# Creating a grouped bar plot in R using barplot() from raw data

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart, series

I have the following data:

```
         CT         VT          TT
A*      5.923076923 6.529411765 5.305555556
Not A*  5.555555556 6.434782609 5.352941176
```

I want to make a grouped bar chart in R from the data such that the grouping is on `A*` and `Not  A*`, the `x-axis` ticks are `CT`, `VT` and `TT` and the numeric values are plotted in the `y-direction`.

What do I need to do to produce the bar plot from this raw `.csv` data?

Answer (score 1):

Next time, you should provide a reproducible example, but I use ggplot2 to create the desired bar plot:

Before jumping into the main body, make sure you have the required packages installed as follows:

```
install.packages(c("ggplot2","data.table"))
```

Now for a stacked bar chart:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(data.table)
data <- data.frame(CT = c( 5.923076923 ,5.555555556), 
                   VT = c(6.529411765,6.434782609), 
                   TT = c(5.305555556, 5.352941176))
rownames(data) <- c("A*", "Not A*")

long_format <- melt(as.matrix(data))

ggplot(long_format, aes(x = Var2,
                        y = value,
                        fill = Var1)) + 
    geom_col()
```

A grouped bar chart:

```
ggplot(data = long_format, 
       aes(x = Var2, 
           y = value,
           fill = Var1)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", 
             stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Hi, this is great, thanks! I'm trying to make a grouped bar rather than a stacked bar, however. I've managed to throw together the following:

require(ggplot2)
require(data.table)
data <- data.frame(CT = c( 5.923076923 ,5.555555556), 
                   VT = c(6.529411765,6.434782609), 
                   TT = c(5.305555556, 5.352941176))
rownames(data) <- c("A*", "Not A*")

long_format <- melt(as.matrix(data))

ggplot(long_format, aes(x = Var2,
                        y = value))

geom_bar(aes(fill = Var1),position="dodge", stat="identity")

Do you know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Hi, this is great, thanks! I'm trying to make a grouped bar rather than a stacked bar, however. I've managed to throw together the following:

 `require(ggplot2) require(data.table) data <- data.frame(CT = c( 5.923076923 ,5.555555556), VT = c(6.529411765,6.434782609), TT = c(5.305555556, 5.352941176)) rownames(data) <- c("A*", "Not A*") long_format <- melt(as.matrix(data)) ggplot(long_format, aes(x = Var2, y = value)) geom_bar(aes(fill = Var1),position="dodge", stat="identity")' 

Do you know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: See my edit in the answer I also added the grouped bar chart.

Comment: Could you mark this as an answer such that this post will be closed?